# Are there function with one local extremum but no global extrema?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Is it possible to find function $f : \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R$ such that $f$ is $C^2$ and has one, and only one local extremum but no global extremum.

I tried to make up an example with this function $f : (x,y) \mapsto e^{-(x^2+y^2)}+2x+2y$ whose graph looks like this :

[image]

I tried to show that $f$ has only one global maximum by showing there exists only one point where $\nabla f(x,y) = 0$ :

I obviously started by calculating, for $x, y \in \mathbb R$, $\nabla f (x,y)$:
$$\nabla f (x,y) = \begin{bmatrix} -2xe^{-(x^2+y^2)}+2\\ -2ye^{-(x^2+y^2) }+2 \end{bmatrix}$$
I need to show that the $\nabla f(x,y) = 0$ has only one solution and that it is a local extremum.

Any help would be apreciated!

Comment: It looks as though you have done it. $\exp(2-(x^2+y^2))\ne0$ for any $x,y$.

Comment: No, I just made a mistake, the $+2$ wasn't meant to be in the exponent...

Comment: Hmmm. So it has no local extremum. You could get it back by giving more weight to the exponential, eg $2\exp(-(x^2+y^2)+x+y$ but then you will get two local extrema.

Comment: It is easy to get a single local **minimum** and no global maximum. That is ruled out by your title, but not by the first sentence of the main text.

Comment: Have you tried proving that the single local extremum has to be a global one? Your condition on the extremum should include a higher-order derivative with non-zero value. Then the only option would be a constant function, but that does not meet the criteria.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a classic question. The easiest example I know is 
$$f(x,y) = x^3+e^{3y}-3xe^y.$$
I leave it to you to show that $f$ has precise one critical point, which is a local minimum. On the other hand, you can show easily that $f$ is unbounded (both ways).

Comment: Thanks!
I found that the only critical point is $(x,y) = (1, 0)$.
We have $\nabla f(1,0) = \begin{bmatrix} 6 & -3 \\ -3 & 6 \end{bmatrix}$ which has eigen values $3$ and $9$, which means it is positive-definite and that $(1,0)$ is a local minimum.
As $f$ is clearly unbounded, you solved my problem well, thanks!

Comment: I used to pose this question to my students every year I taught my Multivariable Mathematics course. Although they didn't come up with formulas, they came up with some great descriptions/models. And, of course, I snuck in this homework question later. I was always amused how some people who'd thought about the question before didn't notice how this answered it specifically. :)